# How can I $watch a js (es6) Set?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

Setting a watcher like

`scope.$watchCollection('vm.mySet', a => console.log(a))`

or

`scope.$watch('vm.mySet', a => console.log(a))`

does not seem to do anything.  Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS has always had a Scope.$watch() function as means to observe [and react to] changes in a given value. With AngularJS 1.1.4, however, they added the Scope.$watchCollection() function as a means to observe changes in a collection (either as an Array or an Object).

Here you are using `controllerAs` syntax. So, use should bind the value you want to watch to `this`. This is as follows:

```
$scope.$watch (angular.bind(this, () => this.mySet), (value) => console.log(value));
```

If it is not controllerAs syntax, you can directly use as follows:

```
$scope.$watch ('mySet', (value) => console.log(value));
```

**The `$watch` works for me to watch changes of es6 set.**

Comment: As yes @Sai, I think you got it re: `controllerAs`, something I fully overlooked.  I will play around with that and will give you the answer if it works.